# DNS: migrating FROM Google Email + Google App hosted website TO Google Email + 3rd party hosting

Tags: google-app-engine, dns, google-apps

I inherited a DNS/website/email scenario I don't understand.

#

I need to modify DNS records so that email integrated with Google Apps is not altered, but so that web traffic goes to a 3rd party.  Currently the web traffic goes to a Google App Engine account (under the previous developers personal account).

On the receiving end, I have a static IP address and the nameservers for the host the web account is on.  I just need to know what to do with them.

I tried changing the A record, but that broke the Google Email integration.  I tried specifying the current A record IP in the MX Host fields, and that was bad, too.

#

Current info:

#

A (Host)
@
216.239.32.21

CNAME (Alias)
e
email.secureserver.net

email
email.secureserver.net

ftp
@

imap
imap.secureserver.net

mail
pop.secureserver.net

mobilemail
mobilemail-v01.prod.mesa1.secureserver.net

pda
mobilemail-v01.prod.mesa1.secureserver.net

pop
pop.secureserver.net

smtp
smtp.secureserver.net

webmail
webmail.secureserver.net

www
ghs.google.com

MX (Mail Exchanger)
20
@
ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM

30
@
ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM

10
@
ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM

40
@
ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.COM

50
@
ASPMX3.GOOGLEMAIL.COM

TXT (Text)
@
google-site-verification=REDACTED

#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really a GAE question, but basically for Google email to work, you only need the 5 MX records.

To host your website somewhere else,

1. change the `@  IN  A  216.239.32.21` to `@  IN  A  <your.new.ip>` which should be given by your new web hosting provider. This will allow you to get to http://yourdomain.com
2. delete the `www  IN  CNAME  ghs.google.com`
3. delete the TXT record for google site verification
4. add `www  IN  CNAME  @` or `www  IN  A  <your.new.ip>`

The secureserver.net addresses I think refer to GoDaddy hosting, and probably don't do anything if you're using gmail - you could probably delete them all.

You might also want to add a cname entry for `mail  IN  CNAME  ghs.google.com.` which will get your users to gmail by typing in http://mail.yourdomain.com

Comment: extremely helpful and accurate.  Thank you very, very much.